# Unreal Engine 4.27.2 -> Widget Blueprint -> Button

Tags: unreal-engine-4

Я нуждаюсь в помощи, пишу игру на ue4 и дошел до создания игрового меню. В момент расставления кнопок на свои места в Widget Blueprint на Canvas Panel не могу понять как централизовать все объекты, а то в ручную не ровно, и когда я уменьшаю размер кнопки то фотография в ней сжимается неравномерно, за место слова: Play, получается: Py, подскажите, как это исправить, пожалуйста